# Identity Server 4 v3.1.2 UserInteraction LoginUrl does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When running Identity Server 4 with a custom loginurl and going to a page on the idsrv itself, for example /grants page. My page is reirected to 'http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fgrants' and not to 'http://localhost:5005/'

I also tried to set the CookieAuthenticationOptions from asp net core authentication settings but without succes. Aldo it's also set by the idsrv itself.. still.

This is the documentation that I used
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html#login-workflow

I'm using this configuration startup:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
  options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "http://localhost:5005/";
})
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);
```

And this my logging output:

```
[15:34:09 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup
You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.

[15:34:14 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using the default authentication scheme idsrv for IdentityServer

[15:34:14 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication

[15:34:14 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in

[15:34:14 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out

[15:34:14 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge

[15:34:14 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Login Url: http://localhost:5005/

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Logout Url: /Account/Logout

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
ConsentUrl Url: /consent

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Error Url: /home/error

[15:34:24 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Error Id Parameter: errorId
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but if anybody still needs to change the `login`/`logout` path, you now need to override `ConfigureApplicationCookie`:

> When using ASP.NET Identity the redirect URLs should have always been configured with ConfigureApplicationCookie

So remove:

```
options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Login";
  options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Logout";
  options.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/Error";
```

Add:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie((obj) =>
{
   obj.LoginPath = "/Login";
   obj.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
   obj.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error";
});
```

See the GitHub issue for more details: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2866

Answer (score 0):

The `LoginUrl` should be local url which identity server could help redirecting user to login , you can check the source code , it would check whether that url is local url :

```
options.LoginPath = ExtractLocalUrl(_idsrv.UserInteraction.LoginUrl);

private static string ExtractLocalUrl(string url)
{
    if (url.IsLocalUrl())
    {
        if (url.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            url = url.Substring(1);
        }

        return url;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, only this worked in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Auth/Login");
    });
```

source: [Identity server 4 not working signin?ReturnUrl=/connect after update IdentityServer4 package from 2.2.0 to 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707421/identity-server-4-not-working-signinreturnurl-connect-after-update-identityser)

The problem is that I was not setting the DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults. After I set this and set the LoginPath, the IDS4 redirected to the login page specified.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**